# Tableview not scroll to bottom with Xcode 9.3 build

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, xcode9

I build my project with Xcode 9.3, but there is bug from apple that my app can not scroll to bottom, does any one has the same issue?
Any idea how to resolve it.

```
- (void)scrollEventListToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{



    CGFloat contentHeight = self.tableview.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat viewHeight = self.tableview.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat scrollY = viewHeight > contentHeight ? 0 : contentHeight - viewHeight + 5.0;
    CGPoint scrollPos = CGPointMake(0, scrollY);

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.tableview.contentOffset = scrollPos;
        }];
    }
    else {
        self.tableview.contentOffset = scrollPos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For who has the same issue for iOS 11 compiled with Xcode 9.3 like me.

If your scroll to bottom doesnt work, I solved the issue with dispatch_after.

```
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // Add you scroll to bottom
           });
```